# Strapi upload files on many fields but same api

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, strapi, headless-cms, jamstack

Hello there JAMSTACK people.

Actually those who chose strapi JS as their headless CMS of choice.

Lets say I have an API named Post, with the following fields.

- title : text
- slug : text
- cover : image
- reference : image
- body : long text
- author : image

And I want to populate data and send it to the API's endpoints for 'POST' & 'PUT' methods.

Any ideas ? Thanks in advance.

PS : I know that for some reason, that's not how exactly we define collection fields' in strapi though, I did this for demonstration's sake.

---

Comment: Please clarify the question, it is not easy to understand what you need. Explain exactly whet you need to do, when, from and what is the expected outcome.

Comment: By "Lets say I have an API named Post, with the following fields" you mean a model?

Comment: Yes pardon my terminology and inability to fully explain.

Here's the expected output :
To attach images on entry creation just like how you would do it in strapi admin panel but this time using react js.

Summary if you wish:
For a given model with fields as described above I want to know specifically how to do an upload request when creating the file. Please note the 2 'image datatypes' defined in the example. 

On an ordinary API call without files I would simple hit '/post'